# Temperature indicator for gnome panel

Tags: 10.10, software-recommendation, indicator, gnome-panel

Is there an indicator (a.k.a applet, launcher) that I can embed to my gnome panel which shows my cpu, gpu, hdd etc. temperatures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sensors-applet` will do the trick for you. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors sensors-applet
```

You should then do `sudo sensors-detect` so that lm-sensors is configured (it will scan sensors in your hardware).

Then simply add "Hardware Sensors Monitor" to the panel. Then, within the context menu, you will be able to configure which sensors will be shown, units, update interval....

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo apt-get install sensors-applet
```

Then when you right click the panel, and go to "Add to panel..." and add a "Hardware Sensors Monitor", you'll see something like this:

[image: sensors-applet]

And yes, as luri points out, you'll also need to set up lm-sensors for this:

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
sudo sensors-detect
```

Go through that and find out what modules need adding (you can have it write to modprobe directly in the last step) and then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check the latest [indicator-sysmonitor](https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor) [build (.deb)](http://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor/trunk/start/+download/indicator-sysmonitor_0.3-1_all.deb), 0.3. It will (eventually, after selecting at least a sensor in Preferences) look like this:

[image: indicator sysmonitor 0.3 with temperature sensor].

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexeftimie/ppa
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor lm-sensors
indicator-sysmonitor
```

I like it more for the simplicity.